# Delayed_job didn't work with action_mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

First, I define a mailer method

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer  
  # customize mail format
  def user_feedback(opts={})
    @v = "Hello"
    @opts = opts
    mail(:to => "xxx@gmail.com", :bcc => ["yyy@gmail.com"],  :subject => "Test")
  end

  handle_asynchronously :user_feedback     
end
```

And, I call this method in a request

```
class MailsController < ApplicationController
  def feedback      
    options[:feedback_time] = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    UserMailer.user_feedback(options).deliver
  end
end
```

Then, I start delay_job worker like this

```
 rake jobs:workoff
```

Here is the log

```
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2809)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2809)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=11) RUNNING
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2809)] No more jobs available. Exiting

[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] Job Class#user_feedback (id=1) RUNNING
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] Job Class#user_feedback (id=1) COMPLETED after 0.0819
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=2)    RUNNING
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] 1 jobs processed at 2.7340 j/s, 0 failed
[Worker(host:localhost.localdomain pid:2208)] No more jobs available. Exiting
```

All of these have done, but the mail is not sent!

Comment: Try not calling .deliver perhaps.  Does UserMailer.delay.user_feedback(options) work?

Comment: This is not work! I change the code, refresh the browsers and restart the worker, then the same output in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call .deliver and add a .delay before the method you are calling on UserMailer

See this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-3-mailers

For example:

```
UserMailer.delay.user_feedback(options)
```

Comment: It sames to be processed, but the mail is still not sent. My rails version is 4.0.4.

Comment: So its creating the delayed job, and the delayed job is running, but its not sending the email?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Before I use delayed_job, email was sent normally. So I think the problem is from delayed_job.

Comment: Although I didn't get through, I think your answer is right(I've seen same operation in source code).

Comment: Its processing your delayed jobs -- you should see more in the development/production log about whats happening to the mail - probably something with your SMTP settings or environment.  You can try using the letter_opener gem to look at the emails get sent.

Comment: It is a little strange. When I rm `handle_asynchronously :user_feedback ` from `UserMailer`, the mail was sent normally!

Answer (score 0):

**Here, I think I need to share my experience of how to get the right answer**

When we use `handle_asynchronously` for a method, it calls `alias_method_chain` to the method, just like the method 'user_feedback' in the question. 
Visit https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/44edd9473adbc415a3e51ead60a63107a9ad41e4/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb for more details

When delayed_job worker going to deal with the delayed send email job, it call a dynamic method, like **user_feedback_without_delay**. And now comes the problem, if we didn't explicitly 
point out the mail template. It'll be trying to find a template like **user_feedback_without_delay.html.erb**.

So, what we should do is to give the template explicitly like this
`mail(:to => "xxx@gmail.com", :bcc => ["yyy@gmail.com"],  :subject => "Test", template_name: 'user_feedback')`